# Accessing GAE DB gives AccessControlException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, google-app-engine, persistence

I have a Java app running on Google's App Engine but I have been unsuccessful in connecting to the database. I am sure this problem must have been asked many times before but I have been unable to find anything that has worked for me. I have played around with the persistence.xml file extensively and I am sure that this is where my problem lies but I cannot see it.

The error log shows:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions: An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup") (SqlExceptionHelper.java:144)

com.mycompany.rfc.web.servlet.ProcessServlet doGet: Problem with servlet operation (ProcessServlet.java:356)
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:273)
at com.mycompany.rfc.data.dao.dbimpl.RfcAccess.getAllOpenForUser(RfcAccess.java:25)
at com.mycompany.rfc.web.servlet.ProcessServlet.doGet(ProcessServlet.java:192)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:145)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:511)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:276)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:312)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:304)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:56)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:161)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:159)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1854)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1831)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2516)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2502)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2332)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2327)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:264)
... 36 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65)
at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:62)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.<init>(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:228)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getPoolManager(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:460)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:84)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
... 56 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:484)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:698)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(CustomSecurityManager.java:55)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(CustomSecurityManager.java:136)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:391)
at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:349)
at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:445)
at java.util.TimerThread.<init>(Timer.java:499)
at java.util.Timer.<init>(Timer.java:101)
at java.util.Timer.<init>(Timer.java:146)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.poolsInit(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:95)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.<init>(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:221)
... 61 more
```

My persistence.xml file is:

    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

```
<persistence-unit name="rfcJPA2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://<IPaddr>:3306/rfc_db" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="<pw>" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="<user>" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"
            value="org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
            value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="0" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I can get things working locally but get the exception when I push the code to the Google Cloud. I have used a MySql client to attach to the database using the IP and credentials in the persistence.xml file.

I have tried using a MySQLDialect Dialect (currently MySQL5Dialect). I am currently using Hibernate version 4.2.0.Final since I have read that later versions spawn threads that are prohibited by Google.

In the stack trace, I have commented line 25 of RfcAccess.

```
public class RfcAccess extends Access implements IRfcAccess, IAccess {

public RfcAccess() {
    super();
}

@Override
public Map<Long, Rfc> getAllOpenForUser(String user) {
    List<?> results = null;
    results = em.createNamedQuery("getAllOpenRfcForUser").setParameter("owner", user).getResultList(); // This is line 25
    if (results == null) {
        return null;
    }
...
}

public class Access implements IAccess {

EntityManager em;

public Access() {
    em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
}

public class EMF {
protected static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = Persistence
        .createEntityManagerFactory("rfcJPA2");

private EMF() {
}

public static EntityManagerFactory get() {
    return emfInstance;
}
}
```

In my ORM I have the following named query

```
<named-query name="getAllOpenRfcForUser">
    <query>select o from Rfc o where o.status = 0 and o.owner = :owner</query>
    <hint name="org.hibernate.timeout" value="200" />
</named-query>
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? Currently the table (Rfc) does not get created in the database. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally sorted out the problem (and learned loads about the way App Engine works in the process). Turns out that C3P0 uses threads - and GAE doesn't allow threads. I have managed to get this working using DBCP.